# How do I remove multiple elements from an array by index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Using a `Array.splice` is fine as long as it's a single value.
Suppose I have an array with 10 elements and I want to remove element 2,4 and 8, using `Array.splice(index,1)` in a `for` loop is a bad idea because the index of each element changes after each splice operation.

How can I remove specific array items and then re-arrange the array accordingly

```
var array = ["Apple", "Banana", "Peach", "Pumpkin", "Tomato", "Mango", "Guava"];

remove(array, 4,5); //Is there a lodash function for this?

//desired result --> ["Apple", "Banana", "Peach", "Guava"]
```

Comment: actually it is not clear, what do you want, just to splice an element at an index or remove more than one element.

Comment: Using `array.splice` works fine,just loop backwards...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a Lodash method [`_.pullAt`](https://lodash.com/docs#pullAt) that pulls elements out of the array (in place) that are specified in an array:

> `_.pullAt(array, [indexes])`
>
> Removes elements from `array` corresponding to `indexes` and returns an array of removed elements.

Thus, apply it like this:

```
var array = ["Apple", "Banana", "Peach", "Pumpkin", "Tomato", "Mango", "Guava"];
_.pullAt(array, [4, 5]);
```

And if you want to pull out non-adjacent items (from the documentation):

> ```
> var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
> var pulled = _.pullAt(array, [1, 3]);
>
> console.log(array);
> // => ['a', 'c']
> ```

This will remove the elements at index 4 and 5 in place, and also return the removed element (if you need it).

---

You could, of course with vanilla JavaScript, look backwards as [Nick A. mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851718/how-do-i-remove-multiple-elements-from-an-array-by-index#comment76684351_44851718) and remove items from the back. The reason this works is because removing from the back will not make a changing `length` an issue. Consider this example where I want to remove the 1st and 3rd elements:

```
[1, 3, 7, 9]
```

If I were to loop 'forwards', I would remove element at index 1 (3), but the length would change to 3 and there would be no element at index 3! If I were to loop backwards though, I would remove the element at index 3 *first* (9). Then the length would be 3, but *that doesn't affect any elements before it*, the element at index 1 is still at index 1 thus removing from the back works.

Comment: Thanks. "pullAt" isn't intuitive though. But yeah, this does exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @NinaScholz It can remove elements that non-adjacent all at once so you don't need to chain splice which would mess with the indexes.

Comment: oh, i see. that should do it.

Answer (score 7):

You can loop reverse :

```
var array = ["Apple", "Banana", "Peach", "Pumpkin", "Tomato", "Mango", "Guava"],
removeFromIndex = [4,5];    
for (var i = removeFromIndex.length -1; i >= 0; i--)
    array.splice(removeFromIndex[i],1);
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tiepnvbn/1xubdswx/)

Comment: so it is important to define the indexes to remove in ascending order? otherwise the resulting array is different?  [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/5hzfjsyv/3/)

Comment: define the indexes to remove in descending order, 
you put removeFromIndex = [5,4];
the first arrays will delete record : "Tomato" index = 4
so now record "Mango" index = 4; Guava = 5;
the second arrays will delete record : "Guava";

   => arrays will be reordered when each record is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you need to take is, removing the elements in a backward manner (*not reversing* the array, as that has the same underlying problem of decrementing the indices of 'not yet checked' elements upon removal.

You can use the [reduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) method, which acts very much like [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), but instead, it iterates an array from (right to left).

Here is an example of how this could be done:

```js
var array = ["Apple", "Banana", "Peach", "Pumpkin", "Tomato", "Mango", "Guava"];

let indexToRemove = [4, 5]; //We're looking to remove "Tomato" & "Mango"

array.reduceRight((_, elem, index) => {
    if (indexToRemove.includes(index)) { //Our condition(s)
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }
});

console.log(array); //Result: [ 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'Pumpkin', 'Guava' ]
```